# Infinite product of fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

The main source of inspiration for this question is this excerpt

> Recall: An ultrafilter on the set X gives you a maximal ideal in the ring of all real-valued functions, and these are the only prime ideals.

from this [MathOverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81011/prime-ideals-in-the-ring-of-germs-of-continuous-functions/81013#81013) of Tom Goodwillie. (In  the same thread there is an outstanding answer of our friend Georges Elencwajg.)

Let $X$ be an infinite set, for each $x$ in $X$ let $K_x$ be a field, and let $A$ be the product of the $K_x$.

Here is what I'd like to know:

$(1)$ What are the maximal ideals of $A$, and what are the corresponding residue fields?

$(2)$ What are the non-maximal prime ideals of $A$, and what are the corresponding residue domains?

$(3)$ What are the non-prime primary ideals of $A$, and what are the corresponding residue rings?

$(4)$ How can one describe the Zariski topology on the prime spectrum of $A$? In particular, does this topology depend only on $X$, or does it really depend on the $K_x$?

For $f$ in $A$ and $x$ in $X$, write $f(x)$ for the $x$ component of $f$, and $f^{-1}(0)$ for the set of all $x$ in $X$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Here are the few things I believe I know:

$(5)$ To each $x$ in $X$ is attached an obvious maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_x$ with residue field $K_x$: the set of all $f$ vanishing at $x$.

$(6)$ More generally, to each ultrafilter $U$ on $X$ is attached the set, which is in fact a prime ideal, of all $f$ such that $f^{-1}(0)$ is in $U$. Then (5) corresponds to the *principal* ultrafilters. But I have no idea about the residue domain associated with a non-principal ultrafilter.

I believe that the answer to (2) is that all primes are maximal.

I (perhaps naively) expect all primary ideals to be prime, and thus maximal.

So, as you see, I need tons of help! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Here is a generalization of one of the subquestions: Does the spectrum of a product of a family of (commutative) rings depend only (up to homeomorphism) on the spectra of the members?

Comment: Excerpt from Mumford's Red Book (p.74): "*Example* G. $\text{Spec}(\prod_{i=1}^\infty k)$, $k$ a field. Those familiar with ultrafilters and similar far-out mysteries will have no trouble proving that this topological space is the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb Z_+$. Logicians assure us that we can prove more theorems if we use these outrageous spaces."

Comment: I was just about to ask the same question myself! To answer (6), the one uses Łoś's theorem to characterise the residue _field_ after quotienting by the maximal ideal corresponding to an ultrafilter. It is an example of an ultraproduct.

Comment: Dear @ZhenLin: Thanks for your comment. I think it would make a great answer...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are absolutely right when you write "I believe that the answer to (2) is that all primes are maximal",  Pierre-Yves :

**Proposition 1**  *The ring $A$ is zero-dimensional.*
**Proof** Recall that a commutative ring $R$ is called von Neumann if  for all $ r\in R$  there exists an $s\in R$  such that  $r=sr^2$.
It is clear that a field is von Neumann and  that a product  of any family of von Neumann rings is von Neumann, so that your ring $A$ is von Neumann.
   But  a von Neumann ring has Krull dimension zero: indeed, if ${\mathfrak p } \subset A$ is prime, the quotient $D:=A/{\mathfrak p } $ is clearly von Neumann.
And to end the proof just  note that  a von Neumann *domain* $D$ is a field: if $d\neq 0\in D$, the  relation $d=rd^2$ implies $1=rd $ so that $d$ is invertible.

**Corollary**  *For every prime (=maximal) ideal* $\mathfrak p\subset A$ *the residue field is*  $\kappa (\mathfrak p)=A_{\mathfrak p}$
**Proof** Since the ring $A$ is reduced, so is its localization, the zero-dimensional (cf.Proposition) ring  $A_{\mathfrak p}$.
 But  then   ${\mathfrak p} A_{\mathfrak p}$ is the nilpotent radical of that reduced ring $A_{\mathfrak p}$ and so must be zero: ${\mathfrak p} A_{\mathfrak p}=0$ .
Hence  we get the (rather unusual !) formula  $\kappa (\mathfrak p)=A_{\mathfrak p}/ \mathfrak pA_{\mathfrak p}=A_{\mathfrak p}/0=A_{\mathfrak p} $ .

And your other hope is true too:
**Proposition 2** *Every primary ideal of* $A$ *is maximal*.
Indeed , since the ring $A$ is von Neumann 
 it is absolutely flat (Atiyah-Macdonald, *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*, Chapter  2, Exercise  27 ) and thus every primary ideal of $A$ is maximal. (Same reference, Chapter 4, Exercise  3)

Answer (score 6):

For (1), there will be variety results depended on the fields.

（1）If $A=\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{F}_p$ then all the residue fields are equal to $\mathbb{F}_p$. (since $x^p=x$)

(2) If $A=\prod_{p}\mathbb{F}_p$, then for any prime $\mathfrak{m}$ containing $\oplus_p\mathbb{F}_p$ , then $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq A/\mathfrak{m}$ and the cardinality of $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is $\aleph$, thus $A/\mathfrak{m}$ is not an algebraic extension. It has transcendental elements over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Proof about the cardinality: define a map $\varphi$ from $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ to $A/\mathfrak{m}$ by sending $(a_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ to $(x_k)$,  $x_k=\sum_{j=1}^na_j2^{j-1}$ if $2^n-1<p_k\leq2^{n+1}-1$. Here index $k$ denotes $k$-th coordinate and $p_k$ denotes the $k$-th prime number. Then $\varphi$ is injective.

> In this case, we want to ask if $A$ is a purely transcendental extension over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

It is not true at least for some maximal ideal!

Consider the equation $x^2+1=0$. Then it can be solved in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if only if $p=1\mod 4$ or $p=2$. Since those primes are infinite, let $a=(a_{p_k})\in A$, $a_{p_k}=1$ if $p_k=1 \mod 4$, then we find a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ containing $\oplus\mathbb{F}_p$  such that $1-a\in \mathfrak{m}$. Hence $x^2+1=0$ can be solvable in $A/\mathfrak{m}$.

But also we can find some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that the $x^2+1=0$ can not be solvable in $A/\mathfrak{m}$.

> The residue fields are always not purely algebraic extension.
>   Since  $(x^2+1)(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$ can be always solvable.

(3) If $A=\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Q}$, the discussion about the cardinality of the residue field is similar.

Those questions  relate to my recent thread [the ring of Cauchy sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86966/the-ring-of-cauchy-sequences).

---

Another  way to show that $\dim A=0$:

suppose we have a proper inclusion between prime ideals, say $\mathfrak{p}\subsetneq\mathfrak{m}$, then you can find an $x\in 
\mathfrak{m}-\mathfrak{p}$ such that the coordinate of $x$ is either $1$ or $0$, then we must have $1-x\in\mathfrak{p}\subset \mathfrak{m}$, contradiction!