# Localization of an infinite product of fields at its maximal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Let $R = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} k$. Due to the answer in this question [Infinite product of fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87981/infinite-product-of-fields), we know that $R$ is zero dimensional, and the localization $R_m$ at every maximal ideal $m \subset R$ is a field. In fact, it is $R/m$. Is $R_m = k$ or is this not true in general for an arbitrary field?

If the statement is not true in general, what is an example where it fails to be true?

Comment: I thinks this is false in general if you assume the Axiom of Choice. For example, the [hyperreal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) can be constructed as an ultrapower of $\mathbb{R}$; that is, taking $R$ to be the set of all sequences on $R$, and moding out by the maximal ideal determined by a particular ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. But the hyperreals are not isomorphic to the reals, at least as an ordered field.

Comment: $R$  is a commutative von Neumann regular ring, and this shows that $\dim R=0$  and $R_m$  is a field for any maximal ideal $m$.                                                                                                                         I guess that for $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and $m$ the maximal ideal containing $\oplus\mathbb{Q}$, the quotient ring $R/m$ has cardinality $c=|\mathbb{R}|$, and therefore it is not isomorphic to $k$.