# $K$-valued functions on an infinite set

Tags: logic, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, filters

This post is inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88062/660) of wxu.

Let $K$ be a field, let $I$ be an infinite set, and let $A$ be the $K$-algebra of all $K$-valued functions on $I$, that is
$$
A=K^I=\prod_{i\in I}K.
$$
Let $\mathfrak a$ be the ideal of $A$ formed by finitely supported $K$-valued functions on $I$, that is
$$
\mathfrak a=K^{(I)}=\bigoplus_{i\in I}K.
$$
Let $\mathfrak m$ and $\mathfrak n$ be two maximal ideals of $A$ containing $\mathfrak a$. In particular the fields $A/\mathfrak m$ and $A/\mathfrak n$ are extensions of $K$.

> Question 1. Are the fields $A/\mathfrak m$ and $A/\mathfrak n$ necessarily isomorphic?

The answer is yes if $K$ is finite. More precisely, in this case we have $A/\mathfrak m\simeq K$. Indeed, let $q$ be the cardinality of $K$ and observe that any element $x$ of $A$, and thus of $A/\mathfrak m$, satisfies $x^q=x$.

But in general we have $A/\mathfrak m\not\simeq K$. For instance if $A:=\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}$, then

(1) $A/\mathfrak m$ has the cardinality of the continuum.

To see this, consider the set theoretical map
$$
\phi:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to A=\mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}
$$
whose $n$-th component
$$
\phi_n:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to\mathbb Q
$$
is defined by
$$
\phi_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n2^ix_i.
$$
We claim that the composition
$$
\pi\circ \phi:\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}\to A/\mathfrak m
$$
of $\phi$ with the canonical projection $\pi:A\to A/\mathfrak m$ is injective. This will imply (1).

Let $x$ and $y$ be two distinct elements of $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$. It suffices to check that $a:=\phi(x)-\phi(y)$ is not in $\mathfrak m$. Writing $a_i$ for the value of $a$ at $i$, there is an $i_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $a_i\neq0$ for $i>i_0$, and thus there is a $b$ in $\mathfrak a\subset\mathfrak m$ such that $a_i+b_i\neq0$ for all $i$, that is $a+b$ is a unit of $A$. This implies $a$ cannot be in $\mathfrak m$, as was to be shown.

Going back to the general setting of Question 1, note that $K$ is algebraically closed in $A/\mathfrak m$. Indeed, let $f\in K[x]$ (where $x$ is an indeterminate) be irreducible of degree at least two, and let $a$ be in $A$. It suffices to show $f(\pi(a))\ne0$, where $\pi:A\to A/\mathfrak m$ is the canonical projection. Since $f(\pi(a))=\pi(f(a))$, we must check that $f(a)$ is not in $\mathfrak m$. But $f(a)$ is a unit of $A$ because we have $f(a)_i=f(a_i)\ne0$ for all $i\in I$.

> Question 2. Is $A/\mathfrak m$ always purely transcendental over $K$?

As indicated above, this is true if $K$ is finite (the transcendence degree being $0$ in this case).

---

**EDIT 1.** Question 2 is a duplicate of [this MathOverflow Question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/326237/461)
of Lisa S. It seems to me Lisa's question is answered by a comment of Tim Campion.

More precisely, Tim says

"if $F$ is algebraically closed, then so is the ultrapower (it is elementarily equivalent). But I don't think any nontrivial purely transcendental extension of any field is algebraically closed..."

If $F$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$, then, as explained in the question, any ultrapower has at least the cardinality of the continuum. In particular such an ultrapower is a *proper* extension of $F$.

I'm taking this opportunity to thank Anonymous for their answer. I'm studying this answer, and will perhaps make further edits, but I wanted to make this one right away.

---

**EDIT 5.** I'm removing Edits 2, 3 and 4. I'm only keeping [this link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/24538/461) to a MathOverflow answer of Joel David Hamkins.

Summary of the answers: Eric Wofsey's answer shows that the answer to Question 1 is No. Tim Campion's argument mentioned in Edit 1 shows that the answer to Question 2 is also No.

Both answerers asked me generously to accept the other answerer's answer!

Comment: I'm glad you found a nice answer to the second question. To comment on the second and third edits, the question of what happens when CH fails may have been open in the past, but it was completely solved in the paper which I linked as "this paper" in my answer. I think your first question is actually still unsolved in the case that CH holds. As Hamkins noted in the MO answer you linked, a theorem of Keisler gives you a conclusion when the structure has cardinality at most $c$, but not in general. I'll edit my answer to add this clarification.

Comment: @Anonymous - Thanks! I hope you agree with my last edit. I now think that it would be better, in order to attract more attention, if I did not accept your answer. (Another option would be that I accept your answer, and YOU ask the "remaining" question as a new MSE Question. Please let me know what you prefer.)

Comment: Thanks. It seems Eric has provided us with a definitive counterexample to the original first question in ZFC. Somehow nonuniform ultrafilters slipped my mind, so I apologize for the overcomplication. I think you should accept Eric's answer, but I will also edit my answer to expand on Tim Campion's MO comment since you mentioned you do not yet understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any infinite field $K$, there exists an infinite set $I$ such that two different nonprincipal ultrapowers of $K$ by $I$ have different cardinalities (and are thus not isomorphic).  Note first that by picking an ultrafilter that countains a countable subset of $I$, you get an ultrapower of cardinality at most $|K|^{\aleph_0}$ (in terms of ideals, this means there is a countable subset $J\subseteq I$ such that the maximal ideal contains all elements of $K^I$ that vanish on $J$).  On the other hand, as mentioned in Anonymous's answer, if the chosen ultrafilter on $I$ is regular, then the ultrapower has cardinality $|K|^{|I|}$.  So, if you choose $I$ such that $|K|^{|I|}>|K|^{\aleph_0}$, there will be two nonprincipal ultrapowers of different cardinality.

Comment: Thanks! About Question 2, it seems to me there was a misunderstanding. I wrote in the post (before the edits) that $K$ is algebraically closed in $A/\mathfrak m$ (and gave I think the same argument as you). But (it seems to me) this doesn't suffice to prove that $A/\mathfrak m$ is not purely transcendental over $K$. However in Edit 1 I quoted an argument of Tim Campion (which I must confess I'm far from understanding) showing the the answer is No. I hope this looks correct to you. To conclude I regard (perhaps mistakenly) Question 2 as solved, and I think you answered Question 1...

Comment: ... As a result I'm planning to accept your answer. But I'd like to have your opinion on one more point. Can you answer the variant of Question 1 when we insist that $I=\mathbb N$? [In the first sentence of your answer "and" should be "an" I think.]

Comment: Er, oops, I wrote this answer in a hurry and was thinking of the wrong definition of "purely transcendental".  Tim Campion's answer is correct--if $K$ is algebraically closed then any ultrapower is algebraically closed, and so is not a purely transcendental extension unless it is the trivial extension.

Comment: I don't know what can be said about Question 1 in ZFC in the special case $I=\mathbb{N}$.  In any case, I think you should accept Anonymous's answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the question you linked, maximal ideals of $K^I$ correspond to ultrafilters of $I$, and consequently, rings of the form $A/\mathfrak{m}$ are the same as [ultrapowers](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct) of $K$. With that in mind, we can approach an answer to your first question.

A positive answer to your first question is not provable from ZFC (assuming ZFC is consistent). A well known example of the fields you discuss is a field of hyperreal numbers which is any ring of the form $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}/\mathfrak{m}$ for a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ containing $\oplus_{n=0}^\infty\mathbb{R}$. As stated by [wikipedia](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number#The_ultrapower_construction) and implied by Theorem 1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.0406.pdf), if CH fails, then there will exist non-isomorphic ultrapowers of $\mathbb{R}$. In fact, $\mathbb{R}$ can be replaced with any real closed field, and the same incident will occur.

However, it gets worse. If $K$ is infinite and the ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ corresponds to what is called a $\textit{regular}$ ultrafilter of $I$, then the cardinality of $A/\mathfrak{m}$ will be the same as that of $A$ due to a [theorem attributed to Keisler](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1971-028-01/S0002-9939-1971-0280361-9/S0002-9939-1971-0280361-9.pdf). Yet, there may exist nonregular ultrafilters. Indeed, [Magidor shows](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1979-249-01/S0002-9947-1979-0526312-2/S0002-9947-1979-0526312-2.pdf) that if the existence of a huge cardinal is consistent with ZFC, then it is consistent with ZFC that there exists a set $I$ and ultrafilter $U$ on $I$ such that the ultraproduct $\omega_0^I/U$ has a strictly smaller cardinality than $\omega_0^I$ does. As such, if we take $K$ to be any countably infinite field, then with the assumptions just stated, there could exist maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$ for which $A/\mathfrak{m}$ and $A/\mathfrak{n}$ do not even have the same cardinality. (Edit: This is overkill. We can obtain a nonregular free ultrafilter by just choosing one which is not not uniform i.e. containing a subset of $I$ with cardinality less than that of $I$. Consequently, this shows in ZFC alone that $A/\mathfrak{m}$ and $A/\mathfrak{n}$ can have different cardinalities. Thanks for the catch Eric Wofsey.)

Edit 1: Due to a theorem of Chang and Keisler in their book "Model Theory", if $I$ is countable, $K$ is a field of cardinality at most $2^{\aleph_0}$, and CH holds, then all ultrapowers of $K$ are isomorphic. However, this does not answer the question when $K$ has cardinality greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $I$ is uncountable and CH holds, so I would consider Pierre's first question still not entirely solved. As I noted earlier, the answer to Pierre's first question is negative if CH fails, but I would be interested to know if the question is provable or refutable (or neither) in ZFC+CH.

Edit 2: I will expand on Tim Campion's Math Overflow comment which yields a negative answer to the second question. It is a consequence of [Los's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct#%C5%81o%C5%9B%27s_theorem) that any structure is elementarily equivalent to all of its ultrapowers, meaning that they satisfy the same first order sentences. In particular, for each positive integer $n$, the sentence $$\forall a_0\forall a_1\ldots \forall a_n\exists x(a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0=0)$$ holds in $K$ if and only if it holds in $A/\mathfrak{m}$. Hence, if we choose $K$ to be an algebraically closed field, then $A/\mathfrak{m}$ will be as well. However, if $A/\mathfrak{m}$ were purely transcendental over $K$, we would have $A/\mathfrak{m}=K(S)$ for some algebraically independent set $S\subset A/\mathfrak{m}$. But $K(S)$ is not algebraically closed when $S$ is nonempty since the polynomial $x^2-s$ is irreducible over $K(S)$ for $s\in S$. If $S$ is empty, then $A/\mathfrak{m}=K$ which need not be the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm confused. You write "If the ideal $\mathfrak m$ corresponds to what is called a *regular* ultrafilter of $I$, then the cardinality of $A/\mathfrak m$ will be the same as that of $A$". If $K$ is finite then so is $A/\mathfrak m$, but $A$ is not.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Sorry, you're right. The theorem I was referencing assumes that the structure is infinite, so it won't apply if $K$ is a finite field. The theorem is referenced in the last paragraph of the "theorem attributed to Keisler" link and is also theorem 9.3 in https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/ultraproducts-web-final.pdf (In theorem 9.3, he uses $A$ where we are using $K$). I'll edit my answer to fix that.

Comment: The existence of nonregular ultrafilters is trivial--just take any ultrafilter that contains a subset of $I$ of strictly smaller cardinality.  What makes Magidor's result interesting is that his ultrafilter is uniform, i.e. it contains no sets of cardinality smaller than that of $I$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for that catch. I was forgetting about nonuniform ultrafilters.